# Removing traiing commas from csv file in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

In a csv file, I have trailing commas that I want to get rid of but the number of commas vary in length. So I cannot use gsub to remove them. Does anyone know a way to read a csv file, remove any trailing commas from the row, and rewrite to the same csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read file line by line and `sub` all trailing `,`s. You cannot directly edit the file so best thing to do is create a `TempFile` and replace your csv file with it when done. Here:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'tempfile'
t_file = Tempfile.new('temp.txt')
File.open("/path/to/csv", 'r') do |f|
f.each_line{|line| t_file.puts line.chomp.sub(/,$/,'') }
    end
t_file.close
FileUtils.mv(t_file.path, "/path/to/csv")
```

Comment: A CSV row can span multiple lines, i.e. "end of line" doesn't have to be "end of row".